# Basic string manipulation to make correct date formatting

Tags: python, date, python-3.x, datetime

Could you help with a small programming problem. I'm trying to make a date in the form dd-mm-YYYY and if my randomly picked day is a 1 digit number I'd add a 0 to the beginining to make e.g. 01052015 for 01-05-2015 instead of 152015.

Here is my code...

```
from random import randint

day = str(randint(1, 29))
if day in range(1,9):
    zero_day = str("0"+day)
else:
    zero_day = day

month = str(randint(5, 10))
if month in range(5, 9):
    zero_month = str("0"+month)
else:
    zero_month = month

split_date= zero_day + zero_month + "2015"

print("Day="+zero_day)
print("Month="+zero_month)
print(split_date)
```

Why does this not work?

it doesn't add any 0's before 1 digit days and months.

Very frustrating, I'm sure it's only a small thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `datetime`module:

```
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

day = randint(1, 29)
month = randint(5, 10)
year = 2015

dt = datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day)
dt_str = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(dt_str)
```

Output is:

```
2015-05-02
```

Answer (score 4):

You are converting the random number to a *string*, and then testing if it is in a range - which consists of integers:

A simple change your code:

```
day = randint(1, 29)
if day < 10:
    zero_day = "0"+str(day)
else:
    zero_day = str(day)
```

Or, even better, you can use string formatting to handle it. Here's an example for the day:

```
zero_day = '{:02d}'.format(randint(1, 29))
```

This will zero pad the random integer. If the number is 0 <= n <= 9 it will have the leading zero as required.

To generate the final date string:

```
random_date = '{:02d}-{:02d}-{}'.format(randint(1,29), randint(5,10), 2015)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
day = str(randint(1, 29))
if day in range(1,9):
```

Your problem is that you are casting the random number to a String to early. Your code checks wether the string "1" is in the range of numbers between 1 and 8 (not 9, you have to add +1). The solution is simple: just cast the number to a string inside the if-block

```
day = randint(1, 29)
if day in range(1,10):      # why not just use day < 10?
    zero_day = "0"+str(day)
else:
    zero_day = str(day)
```

Answer (score 0):

The range function is not inclusive. So **range(5,9)** generates 5,6,7,8. Also range  generates integers and not strings.